# WebView issue in samsung android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery, flutter

i have android app with web-view option inside it to show some data. web-view data(HTML Content) coming fine in other devices but in samsung android devices like a50, note etc UI is coming with extra scale and also some event is not working at right place.

we are using html, css, bootstrap, jQuery web content in flutter app. for reference i attached two screenshot.
[Image 1 with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yVRJ.jpg) and here is image and here is [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65ORv.png)

Comment: you should check css media queries, check for width. also check for the font-size and weight.

Comment: @Noman already checked but its not about css because with same width on other device its working fine

Comment: did you try reducing the `min-width`? how did you align the images in the menu? are you using position absolute with left or right properties, it seems they are not align based on relatively

Comment: not using min-width for menu and using image as background-image, and i hope its not html or css issue, its android webkit issue may be because same code base working on other android devices